# Tensorflow `tf.layers.batch_normalization` doesn't add update ops to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code (copy/paste runnable) illustrates using `tf.layers.batch_normalization`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(tf.constant([0.0]))
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))

> []     # UPDATE_OPS collection is empty
```

Using TF 1.5, the documentation (quoted below) clearly states that **UPDATE_OPS should not be empty** in this case (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization):

> Note: when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be
>   updated. By default the update ops are placed in
>   `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`, so they need to be added as a dependency to
>   the train_op. For example:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your code to be in training mode (by setting the `training` flag to `True`) as mentioned in the [quote](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization):

> Note: when **training**, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be updated. By default the update ops are placed in tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, so they need to be added as a dependency to the train_op.

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(tf.constant([0.0]), training=True)
 print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))
```

will output:

```
[< tf.Tensor 'batch_normalization/AssignMovingAvg:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
 < tf.Tensor 'batch_normalization/AssignMovingAvg_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

and Gamma and Beta end up in the TRAINABLE_VARIABLES collection:

```
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES))

[<tf.Variable 'batch_normalization/gamma:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
 <tf.Variable 'batch_normalization/beta:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Comment: Thanks! That was obvious in hindsight. For completeness, I've edited your answer to show that Gamma and Beta end up in the TRAINABLE_VARIABLES collection.

Comment: Oh, I had actually done `trainable=True` rather than `training=True`, a gotcha if anyone else pulls the same mistake.

Comment: If `training` is a tensor variable then it doesn't work as expected. If `training` is false, `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` still returns all batch norm update ops.