# Tensorflow low level api, batch normalization problem

Tags: tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization, tf.keras

The [tf.layers.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) documentation says it will be removed in a future version, and should be replaced by [tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization), but i cannot find a way to replace the functionality using tensorflow low level api.

```
import tensorflow as tf
bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(tf.constant([0.0]), training=True)
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))
```

which outputs:

```
[<tf.Operation 'batch_normalization/AssignMovingAvg' type=AssignSub>,
<tf.Operation 'batch_normalization/AssignMovingAvg_1' type=AssignSub>]
```

If we instead use keras as suggested in the documentation

```
bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(tf.constant([0.0]), training=True)
```

we get an empty output:

```
[]
```

Since UPDATE_OPS is empty, the model is unable to update the batch normalization moving_avg_mean and moving_avg_variance during training using keras (resulting in a much higer test error). Any suggestion how to solve this is greatly appreciated!

The example above is taken from an older post of how to use [tf.layers.batch_normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874558/tensorflow-tf-layers-batch-normalization-doesnt-add-update-ops-to-tf-graphke)

Comment: FYI and future use, there is now a dedicated tag for the Keras API as part of Tensorflow (added).